# Class-Dump Installation

Tags: objective-c, macos

So this may sound like a really stupid question and I *HAVE* looked at the how-to from the parent website, but no matter what I do, I cannot get this program to even start to install...

I tried entering:
cd /opt/local/bin/portslocation/dports/class-dump

which returned a "this file/director doesnt exist" error, so i tried to get to it folder by folder.  when i got all the way to:
cd /opt/local/bin/
i cannot go any further. when i check the contents of the bin directory, the only files i can find are (and i cannot access these apparently either):
"daemondo port  portf  portindex portmirror"
i have tried doing this on 2 computers so far to no avail, macports is installed on both like the website said and i am having trouble finding any support for it.  please and thank you!!

Answer (score 7):

Unless you're trying to develop it, why screw around? Use [`homebrew`](http://brew.sh). As of today, and modulo a `sudo` here or there, you can install `homebrew` with

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

If this doesn't work for you, check the command line at the top of the page on [`homebrew`](http://brew.sh).†

After this, install `class-dump` with

```
brew install class-dump
```

Done.

---

† Ping me in the comments with "command line update needed", and I'll try to keep this in sync. :)

Comment: Website is now http://brew.sh, command is now `ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"`.

Comment: Brew install has moved. New command is ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"

Answer (score 4):

I had issues with this for hours, but it is actually quite simple.

I downloaded the class-dump 3.3 version from CodeTheCode, Unzipped the file and copied the class-dump file to a directory.  In my case the directory was /opt/theos/bin.

In terminal, I then CD to that directory using cd /opt/theos/bin
To run the class dump command line utility it is as simple as this;

```
./class-dump
```

Obviously you then need to give it it's arguments, so in my case I was using it do dump the iOS headers from the frameworks, so I used;

```
./class-dump -H   /Developer/Library/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit -o ~/Desktop/UIKit
```

Obviously I am not sure what you are using it for, but in the example above I am telling class-dump to dump header files from the directory given, and output them to /Desktop/UIKit.

The theory is carried throughout.

Comment: Thanks helped me a lot,..Can I check aperticulary binary is compatible with somearchitecture or not?

Comment: With Xcode 4.4 the path has changed (change the sdk version as needed): ./class-dump -H /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/PassKit.framework -o

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried getting the binary from http://www.codethecode.com/projects/class-dump/?